# Branding assets are not working for tvOS after update to Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, tvos, xcode11

[image: Screenshot]

I am working on an app that has iOS and tvOS versions. After the update to Xcode 11 the Branding Assets for the tvOS version started to glow in red. It seems that Xcode can't find them. I tried making a brand new project for tvOS and the result is the same!

After contacting the Apple support they confirmed that this is a bug and said that they are working on it. However a lot of time passed since then ...

I am writing this question to see, if other people have bumped into this problem and, if someone has found a workaround.

This bug actively prevents me to release new versions of the tvOS app via Xcode 11+.

I will write here if Apple responds with a fix for the problem, so other people may know, if a solution has been made available via the official channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed in Xcode 11.3. The UI no longer glows red as shown in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Same here...

Setting the "Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name" in Build Settings manually did the trick for me (App Icon Source still shows up in red, but the icons are being used now).

[Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7EMF.png)

[Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx2SB.png)

[Warning still present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOXxQ.png)

PS: Also I removed the following lines from Info.plist. Not sure what actually solved the issue.

```
<   <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<   <dict/>
<   <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<   <dict/>
```

Comment: Can you archive and distribute the application, because I have done that, the icons and splash are being used, but when archiving the application for distribution I receive error that I haven't specified branding assets.

Comment: Yes, archived and committed to the Appstore right away. I'll probably have to do the same for another project on Monday. I'll then have another look into this...

Comment: Thanks a lot, will wait to hear from you!